# Do we have different log buffers available in kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

Till now my understanding is that there is one kernel log buffer which is used for printk and printk can be called from any where. I was trying to increase the log buffer size with `CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT` , but in `menuconfig` I have seen one more `NMI_LOG_BUF_SHIFT`. When searching in net it says `Temporary per-CPU NMI log buffer`. Do we have different log buffers in kernel (say one is for interrupt , other is for non interrupt purpose etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From most kernel contexts (including interrupt handlers), printk() works correctly.

However there are exceptions:

- implementation of printk itself, or serial drivers called from there
- NMI (non-maskable interrupt), which may happen while executing code of printk itself

To make it possible to print even from these contexts, there is alternate buffer. It is per-cpu and thus requires no locking. It is expected to be used very rare. Messages are copied from there to main buffer in safe context.

After 4.10 it is controlled by CONFIG_PRINTK_SAFE_LOG_BUF_SHIFT